# I need to open a specific page on a TabControl, which is on a form that has two TabControls

Tags: vba, ms-access, tabcontrol

I have a Form named **frmSearchAirport**

I have two tab controls on the form named **TabControl1** and **TabControl2**.
Each tab control has five pages.

On another Form i have command buttons.

**I want to use each command button to open a page on a TabControl and to make the inactive TabControl invisible**

I wrote this code for one of the command buttons so that it would open the first page on TabControl2 and and make TabControl1 invisible but **i get an error message saying the action or method requires a form name argument**

```
DoCmd.OpenForm FormName:=frmSearchAirport, View:=acNormal, OpenArgs:=0
Forms![frmSearchAirport].TabControl1.Visible = False
```

and this code for the On Load event of the Form named frmSearchAirport

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

  If IsNull(Me.OpenArgs) = False Then
    Me.TabControl1 = Me.OpenArgs
      Me.TabControl2 = Me.OpenArgs
  End If

End Sub
```

Can anyone help with this.

Thank you

**Edit 1:**

Ive since changed the code to this and im getting **an Application Defined or Object Defined error**

```
DoCmd.OpenForm FormName:="frmSearchDublinAirport", View:=acNormal,OpenArgs:=0
Forms![frmSearchDublinAirport].Form.TabControl1.Visible = False
```

**Edit 2:**

ive changed the code to this. The form is actually opening on the correct page but the other TabControl is still visible and the pop up error message appears saying Application Defined or Object Defined error

```
DoCmd.OpenForm FormName:="frmSearchAirport", View:=acNormal, OpenArgs:=0
Forms![frmSearchAirport].TabControl1.Visible = False
```

**Edit 3:**

This code is working. the problem was I named the TAbControl incorrectly. I used TabControl1 instead of TabControlOne

```
DoCmd.OpenForm FormName:="frmSearchAirport", View:=acNormal, OpenArgs:=0
    Forms![frmSearchAirport].TabControlOne.Visible = False
```

Answer (score 0):

The `FormName` parameter of `DoCmd.OpenForm` needs a string - the form name.

So you probably need:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm FormName:="frmSearchAirport", View:=acNormal, OpenArgs:=0
```

Comment: you are correct about the string but now when i run it im getting an Application Defined or Object Defined error

Comment: @frustrationmultiplied: Where exactly? Please check [How to debug VBA code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx)

Comment: Sorry i changed the code to Forms![frmSearchAirport].Form.TabControl1.Visible = False and this is giving the Application or Object Defined error

Comment: @frustrationmultiplied: `.Form` is not needed in there. Perhaps `TabControl1` is the first control in the tab order, so it gets the focus? Then you can't hide it. Define another control as first in tab order.

Comment: if i dont use .Form i get an error message saying the action or method requires a form name argument. u could be right about the focus

Comment: I changed the TAb order so that TabControl2 was first but i still get the error message